# collecting data fromcollect data in the "ADOTable" into txt access

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I create applications with `C ++ Builder XE` and `ms access 2010`.

by: `ADOConnection` > `ADOTable` > `DataSource` > `DBGrid`.

how to collect the data that appear in the `DBGrid`.
I know use this code:

```
AnsiString tmpText;
tmpText+=ADOTable2->FieldByName("Name")->AsString;
```

but could not take all of the data that is in `DBGrid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
ADOTable1->First(); // go to first record
for(int i = 0; i < ADOTable1->RecordCount; i++){
    // read all columns needed by using ADOTable1->FieldByName("FieldName")->As..
    ADOTable1->Next(); // go to next record
}
```